# Erlang 16B01 no longer receives udp messages from arduino

Tags: erlang, arduino

Did something change in the default UDP listening behavior for Erlang 16?  I wrote the following code that sends temperature and humidity via UDP every 2 seconds:

```
unsigned int sendPort = 8888;
IPAddress sendIp(10, 0, 1, 16);

Udp.beginPacket(sendIp, sendPort);
Udp.write(ReplyBuffer, 8);
Udp.endPacket();
```

Erlang R15 on a mac seemed to receive the packets fine:

```
Erlang R15B03 (erts-5.9.3.1) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.9.3.1  (abort with ^G)
1> {ok,S}=gen_udp:open(8888,[]).
{ok,#Port<0.581>}
2> flush().
Shell got {udp,#Port<0.581>,{10,0,1,26},8888,[0,0,0,220,0,0,2,179]}
Shell got {udp,#Port<0.581>,{10,0,1,26},8888,[0,0,0,220,0,0,2,179]}
ok
```

But in Erlang R16B01 on a mac it doesn't receive anything:

```
Erlang R16B01 (erts-5.10.2) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false] [dtrace]

Eshell V5.10.2  (abort with ^G)
1> {ok,S}=gen_udp:open(8888,[]).
{ok,#Port<0.580>}
2> flush().
ok
```

A simple python script also receives the UDP messages.

Comment: Did you test without connection options, `{ok,S}=gen_udp:open(8888, []).` and R16B01 for the start?

Comment: And also you'll send to `10, 0, 1, 16`, but you not specify ip in `udp` listener, i think you must send to the `127.0.0.1`, there is default listener.

Comment: I tested with the same options in R15 and R16.  I don't think I can set which address to listen to.  I made another attempt at speciffing all the arguments I could `gen_udp:open(8888,[inet, binary,{recbuf, 100}, {read_packets, 1}, {ifaddr,{10,0,1,16}}, {ip, {10,0,1,16}}, {multicast_loop, true}, {active, true}, {add_membership, {{10,0,1,26}, {10,0,1,16}}}, {deliver, term}, {dontroute, true}, {header, 0}, {mode, binary}, {read_packets, 1}])` but got the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an idiot.  It was the mac firewall.  The firewall preferences were set to block incoming traffic for the one version of erlang but not the other.